# PHP spontaneously creates associative array where indexed array is required - using PHP arrays with Highcharts

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I'm using PHP to retrieve data from an SQL database to produce a stacked column chart in Highcharts.  The idea is that I'm taking the following piece of code to retrieve values from my database.  This code should generate an array which then gets encoded to JSON and passed to Highcharts; this code produces a single 'part' of a stacked column, and the index determines which vertical bar that part is in.  (So in http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked, the index would represent which fruit, and the data in this series would represent one person/color.)

The issue is that when I run this code, instead of ending up with an indexed array of data grouped by category, such as 
[12,13,14,15] where each item is a category, I end up with an associative array where the indexes I specified in the code are turned into a string key. 
{"1":13,"0":12,"3":14, "2":13, "5":15}
Because my indexes are being interpreted as associative keys and not as the indexed locations of the data inside the array, the data is now being added to locations in the order that I retrieved the data, and not assigned to a location in the array based on the index I give. Highcharts assigns categories based on location in the array, and not on key, so all my data ends up in the wrong categories.

Is there a way to get PHP to treat my carefully collected indexes as indexes and not as keys, and add my data points in the location in the array indicated by the indexes? I'm kind of new to PHP, and Java and C++ - the languages I've worked with before - don't have associative arrays, so any help you can give me in explaining and fixing this undesired behavior would be much appreciated.

Code below.
`$variable` indicates what the data is being sorted into categories by, and `$r` is the variable representing the array of the SQL query, so `$r['variable']` is the category of this data point, and `$r['amount']` is the data point itself.

```
$found = -1;
//if this is the first set of data being collected
if (count($category['data']) == 0){
$category['data'][0] = $r[$variable]; 
$series1['data'][0] = floatval($r['amount']);
$count++;
$times1[0]++;
}


//if it's not the first set of data, find out if this category has been used before
else {
for ($x = 0; $x < count($category['data']); $x++){
    if ($r[$variable] == $category['data'][$x]){
$found = $x;
break;
}
}
// if that category does not already exist, add it, and add the data
if ($found == -1) { 
$times1[$count]++;
$category['data'][$count] = $r[$variable];
$series1['data'][$count] = floatval($r['amount']);
$count++;

}
else {  //otherwise, add its data to the data already in the current category.  This will eventually yield an average, with $times1[] as the divisor
$times1[$found]++;
$series3['data'][$found] = floatval((floatval($series3['data'][$found]) + floatval($r['amount'])));

}}
```

Comment: Based on your dumped JS object, you're assigning `[1]` before `[0]`, which confuses PHP into handling this as an associative array. Can you precalculate the number of categories you will have and then prefill the array with that many zeroes (`array_fill($r['variable'], $number_of_categories, 0`)? Alternatively, try sorting the array keys with `ksort($r['variable'])` after populating it.

Comment: @DCoder - Both of those worked, but ksort is a better fit here because it doesn't lock me into having a certain number of categories. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Go through with below code hope it will give some idea to resolve your problem --    
<?php

    $jsonstring = '{"1":13,"0":12,"3":14, "2":13, "5":15}';
    $tempArr =  json_decode($jsonstring, true);
    asort(tempArr); // for sorting the array --

    //run another foreach to get created an array --

    $finArr =  array();
    foreach(tempArr as $key=>$val){
    $finArr[] = $val;
    }

    $requiredjsonString = json_encode(finArr); // it will return your required json Array [12,13,14,15]

    ?>
```

Edit: I advice also set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag in json_encode();